# Pandas - Convert dataframe format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking how to convert from this format:

```
Date        Open        High        Low         Close       Adj Close   Volume                  
2020-01-22  167.399994  167.490005  165.679993  165.699997  163.963043  24138800
```

Into this:

```
            Open        High        Low         Close       Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2020-01-22  167.399994  167.490005  165.679993  165.699997  163.963043  24138800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

Or you could do `inplace` like:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Then:

```
print(df)
```

Would give:

```
            Open        High        Low         Close       Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2020-01-22  167.399994  167.490005  165.679993  165.699997  163.963043  24138800
```

Comment: How did you even understand what was going on here..